# loading dictionaries from a file with C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, load

I have dictionaries. First I initialize them.

```
    public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup;
    public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup2;
    public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup3;
```

Then dictionaries are loaded on button_click event.

```
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true); lookup.Add("1", l1);
    // add hundreds more
    }
```

the problem is that this code takes up nearly half of my main file space, so I was thinking about creating a separate file to load dictionaries from it.

so I tried to create a separate class (cs) file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace getDictData
{
    class mydict
    {
        public static void loadDict()
        {
            Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
            Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true); lookup.Add("1", l1);
        }
    }
}
```

in the main file I add:

```
using getDictData
```

and use it like this:

```
 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 mydict.loadDict();
 }
```

nothing seems to be working.. so **how do you load methods from different files with C#?**

**EDIT: I'm using this code to check if something was loaded into a dictionary:**

```
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var targer = lookup.ToList(); // error is thrown here
        string s = targer[0].Key;
        textBox6.Text = "" + s;
    }
```

the result is always null, no matter how I change the code.

"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"

and if I delete dictionary initialization from main file I'm getting

"The name 'lookup' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `nothing seems to be working` what is nothing?

Comment: Looks correct. Does it compile? What do you mean by "half your file space"? What makes the loading code so large? If there are lots of bitmaps to load, perhaps you should just load all images from a directory? Also: C# code typically has namespaces, class names and method names beginningwith uppercase letters.

Comment: You are using a separate namespace to do the processing???

Comment: by "nothing seems to be working" I mean - nothing is loaded into dictionary.. wait a sec and see edit*

Comment: Also, you should use `lookup.Count` to check if something is loaded.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata opps.. yes it's actually easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble you are facing is something very trivial. Indeed you can write functions in different files, classes etc and thats how it has to be done. If you try this, it definitely would work.

```
public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup;
public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup2;
public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup3;

 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     lookup = mydict.loadDict(); //now that you have loaded it.
 }
```

Your class should be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace getDictData
{
    class mydict
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Bitmap> loadDict()
        {
            Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
            Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true); lookup.Add("1", l1);
            return lookup;
        }
    }
}
```

And now,

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var targer = lookup.ToList(); //hopefully lookup is not null anymore    

    if (lookup.Count == 0) //or whatever way you want to validate depending upon the indexing u use
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No valid items"); //or something similar that you dont get index out of bound exception.
         return;
    }

    string s = targer[0].Key;
    textBox6.Text = "" + s;
}
```

Edit: I guess there are just a few dictionaries to be loaded. You could do this instead to answer your question in comment, but not elegant at all.

1) Return a list of dictionaries from dictionary loading class:

Your Dictionary loading class:

```
   class mydict
   {
       public static List<Dictionary<string, Bitmap>> loadAllDicts()
       {
           List<Dictionary<string, Bitmap>> lookups = new List<Dictionary<string, Bitmap>>();

            Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup1 = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
            Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true); 
            lookup1.Add("1", l1);
            lookups.Add(lookup1);

            Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup2 = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
            Bitmap l2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true); 
            lookup2.Add("1", l2);
            lookups.Add(lookup2);

            //etc

            return lookups;
        }
    }
```

2) And then

```
   private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        List<Dictionary<string, Bitmap>> lookups = mydict.loadAllDicts();

        lookup = lookups[0];
        lookup2 = lookups[1];
        lookup3 = lookups[2];
   }
```

Comment: great! it actually worked, but in a slightly different way than I expected. Is it possible to load all dictionaries in one method, rather than creating "loaddict1(), loadDict2(), ..." for each dictionary and calling "lookup1 = mydict.loadDict1(); lookup2 = mydict.loadDict2();"? well, not such a great deal, but anyway.. thanks for help again

Comment: @Alex do you have hundreds of such dictionaries? I guess just 4 or 5? In that case going by the same approach is more straight forward, and readable.

Comment: you are most certainly right about "readability" issue.. I have about 9 dictionaries - some have 75 keys (so that's seventy five lines of code), some 40, or even 10 .. i guess keeping them separated is a good thing after all.

Comment: even by the code I edited, it would take almost the same number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  `Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();` is defined in your static method `loadDict()` and has no reference to outside. How would you get that data? You could add a property to your mydict class.

```
class mydict
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Bitmap> MyLookup { get; private set; }
    public static void loadDict()
    {
                    MyLookup.Clear();
        Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true);
        MyLookup.Add("1", l1);
    }
}
```

Now , call `mydict.loadDict();` and then you can access your bitmaps through

```
mydict.MyLookup
```

Or use a function with a return value.

```
 public static Dictionary<string, Bitmap> loadDict()
        {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
            Bitmap l1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.bmp", true);
            dict .Add("1", l1);
                    return dict;
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately I got an error.. but @Alex thank you for your solution! I'm going to stick with different method for now.